# saving modelsummary() output to Excel

Tags: r, modelsummary

I have a list of models. The **modelsummary** documentation mentions being able to save to Excel format (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modelsummary/modelsummary.pdf). I can't get it to work. If Excel isn't possible, is there another 'spreadsheet'-type format? I like to be able to compactly annotate my output within different rows and columns and make notes. Docx output is way too clunky for that. I realize I can output as .html and then open and save it as Excel ... but that's a lot of clicking ... I'm running a lot of models.

An example:

```
library(modelsummary)
models = list(
  "mpg" = lm(mpg ~ vs, data = mtcars),
  "am" = glm(am ~ vs, family = binomial, data = mtcars),
  "wt" = lm(wt ~ vs, data = mtcars)
    )

modelsummary(models, stars = TRUE, output = "models.xlsx")
```

An error is then thrown:

> Error in sanitize_output(output) :    The `output` argument must be
> default, gt, kableExtra, flextable, huxtable, html, jupyter, latex,
> latex_tabular, markdown, dataframe, data.frame, modelsummary_list, or
> a valid file path with one of these extensions: html, tex, md, txt,
> docx, pptx, rtf, jpg, png

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied your code and note where it fails.

Comment: based on the rdocumentation of ```modelsummary()``` The ```output``` argument only states what kind of output it will be. This also what the error is telling you: if you want excel your argument should be ```output  = "xlsx" ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @Omniswitcher. The argument `output  = "xlsx"` produces the same error.

Comment: How about `x <- modelsummary(models, stars = TRUE, output = "gt")` and then `openxlsx::write.xlsx(x, "foo.xlsx")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output to `data.frame` and then write the file to CSV (using `write.csv`) or XLSX files (using the `openxls` package). Excel will be able to open files in either format:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(openxlsx)

models = list(
  "mpg" = lm(mpg ~ vs, data = mtcars),
  "am" = glm(am ~ vs, family = binomial, data = mtcars),
  "wt" = lm(wt ~ vs, data = mtcars))

tab <- modelsummary(models, stars = TRUE, output = "data.frame")

write.csv(tab, "models.csv")

write.xlsx(tab, "models.xlsx")
```

Edit:

With the development version of `modelsummary`, this is now possible:

```r
modelsummary(models, output = "models.csv")
modelsummary(models, output = "models.xlsx")
```

Comment: If you want formatting you can also output to huxtable and then use `huxtable::as_Workbook()`, which again uses openxlsx on the backend.